# async and await not workingg

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

its not waiting for validation and just run the else part :| where is my mistake?

```
  async validateBeforeSubmit(event) {
        await  this.$validator.validateAll().then(  result => {
            if (result) {
                 console.log(result); // just log the -> true
                // go submit
            }else{
                console.log(result);  // just log the -> false
                event.preventDefault();
                var elmnt = document.getElementById("drop_zone");
                elmnt.scrollIntoView();
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>console.log(error));
    },
```

i'm using veevalidator and i define some custom rules that need afew seconds to resolve:

```
 created() {
        this.$validator.extend('unique', {
            //   getMessage: field => 'At least one ' + field + ' needs to be checked.',
            async validate(value, arg) {
                arg = arg[0];
                let sw = false;
                if (arg == 'n_code') {
                    let data = {
                        'n_code': value
                    }
                    await Axios.post(duplicate_ncode, data, {
                        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content') }
                    })
                        .then((response) => {
                            if (response.data == true) {
                                sw = true;
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                    if (sw) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                if (arg == 'email') {
                    let data = {
                        'email': value
                    }
                    await Axios.post(duplicate_email, data, {
                        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content') }
                    })
                        .then((response) => {
                            if (response.data == true) {
                                sw = true;
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                    if (sw) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                if (arg == 'mobile') {
                    let data = {
                        'mobile': value
                    }
                    await Axios.post(duplicate_mobile, data, {
                        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content') }
                    })
                        .then((response) => {
                            if (response.data == true) {
                                sw = true;
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                    if (sw) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                // console.log('questions', value, testProp, options.some((option) => option[testProp]));
                // return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

when user fill all fields it will check 3 api and that need momnets to check.
and i need to await to get the answer but there is somthing wrong which is not working.

please help

Comment: You are using two different patterns. Async and await, and event chaining callbacks.

Comment: What is `this.$validator`? If it really returns a promise, then this code should wait for whatever the promise represents to finish before continuing. (It's not idiomatic, as @CodeMonkeyForHire points out, but what you have above should *work*. Just FWIW, [this](https://pastebin.com/d1QDXBL1) would be the idiomatic version assuming `validateBeforeSubmit` should never allow its promise to be rejected [just like your code above].)

Comment: If you run this right now, what is the actual message that shows in the console?

Comment: form will submited and show nothig , because it will not wait for the response , but if i use event.preventDefault(); at the top to stop the submiting it will show the result of validating after 3 second which is true if validating is true and is false if validating is false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
async validateBeforeSubmit(event) {
  try {
    const result = await this.$validator.validateAll();
    if (result) {
      // go submit
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      var elmnt = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
      elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
},
```

Comment: maybe i have mistake some where else,i run this function on ` v-on:submit="validateBeforeSubmit" ` on form tag.

Comment: Please add a `console.log(result)` and add the output in your question

Comment: i added it to the answer with some more detail